# Number of odd $n$ such that $n(n+2)$ is divisible by odd $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Goodmorning,
I would like to prove the following lemma: let $p>1$ be an odd integer, then
$$\#\{n\leq2p : n \text{ odd}, \quad p\mid n(n+2)\}=2^{\nu(p)}$$
where $\nu(p)$ is the number of different prime factor of $p$. I only need an idea of solution, no formalism is required.

Note that if $p=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$, we can assume $e_i=1$ for all $i$, in fact each $p_i$ cannot divide both $n,n+2$. Then, let's assume $p=p_1\cdots p_k$.

If $k=1$ it's obvious. So only need to prove it for $p=p_1p_2$, the result will follow by induction.

Comment: Downvoted.  Where is your work?  In particular, what happens if $\nu(p)$ = 1 (e.g. $p=5$).  Having analyzed that, what happens if $\nu(p)$ =2 (e.g. $p=15$).  Unclear whether induction will prove lemma, but it **might**.  Therefore, you should definitely explore as indicated, **before you post**, and **then edit** your post to include such exploration.

Comment: A more common notation for the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ is $\omega(n)$

Comment: I obviously worked on the problem before posting it: the original one was harder than this, this problem is the consequence of simplification of the original one (my work is to have reduced the original problem to this simple identity, I was only asking some tips to solve it). Obviously this has to be formalised by induction on $\nu(p)$, I only need to solve it when $p=p_1p_2$ with $p_i$ prime.

Comment: It's a little bit useless to comment saying "you can solve it by induction" when the problem is obviously not there.

Comment: I thought that those formal semplification were obvious, but since they seems not to be, I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it.

If $n$ odd is such that $0\leq n \leq 2p$, then $n=2t+1$ for $t\in\{0,...,p-1\}$.

So we can think at this problem as counting the roots of a polynomial:

$$\#\{n\leq 2p : n \text{ odd}, p\mid n(n+2)\}=\#\{x\in \mathbb{Z}_p : f(x):=(2x+1)(2x+3)\equiv 0 \pmod{p}\}$$

Now we write $p = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$. The number of solutions modulo $p_i$ are obviously $2$:
$$x_1=\frac{p-1}{2} \qquad x_2=\frac{p-3}{2}$$
Note that they are distinct. Now
$$f'(x)=8x+8\equiv 0 \pmod{p} \Longleftrightarrow x\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$
Note that $-1 \pmod{p}$ cannot be root of $f(x)$. Thus, for Hensel's Lemma, we have that $f(x)$ has exactly $2$ distinct roots modulo $p_i^{e_i}$, for all $i$.

Finally, the roots modulo $p$ are all the possible combinations of those ones and so they are exactly $2^k$.